# Django exercises

Tags: python, django

I did enough search in google before posting here about this topic and I didn't find what I am searching for.
I just finished learning Django. Now,I would like to practise Django and become an expert in Django. I would like to practise Django by doing simple,intermediate and expert level Django exercises and assignments. Where Can I find such assignments or exercises?

Answer (score 1):

Django book itself covers a lot but you will learn when you can work on some project or task. All it is a matter of practice.

Choose any best website to implement from internet that you can implement and work on it to the end with some deadlines so that you can come across different issues and learn more from those.

I would recommend you to work on a single db first and finish these tutorials before https://www.gitbook.com/book/djangogirls/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/details  and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/